# google plus and pinterest share: how to not show unwanted images

Tags: google-plus, pinterest

When user try to share my page on google plus, google gives suggestions for some extra images which I don't want. I wan't only one image to show up in share windows. Is any way to tell that? I already use og:image tag, but it doesn't help.

The same problem is when Google Chrome Pin it extension is used for Pinterest.

Comment: I just found solution for pinterest - nopin="nopin". Still looking for something like that for Google plus.

Answer (score 0):

Although Google+ generally respects the "og" tags, it frequently has trouble doing so. What works much better is to use Schema.org microdata. You can find a configuration tool to help, and some very brief documentation, at https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/.

More information about Schema.org markup is available at https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1211158.

Comment: To add to @Prisoner's answer, I'm not aware of any method to tell the G+ fetcher not to use specific images. You can [open a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/entry?template=Feature%20Request%20-%20Plugins) if you would like something added to the API.